# How do I find a matching subtree?

Tags: search, tree, subtree, truncated

I have a large binary tree, T.  T "matches".  Some number of subtrees of T will also match.  In fact, the matching subtrees need not even be full subtrees: they can be truncated, too.  By truncated subtree, I mean that nodes in the subtree may not contain children all the way down - some nodes that have children may have their children removed.

An example: see [this link](http://forte.fh-hagenberg.at/Project-Homepages/Blindenhund/conferences/granada/papers/PUERINGER/PUERINGER_files/image001.jpg).  The tree represented by poem1, stanza1, stanza2, line3 is an example of a truncated subtree.

Determining if a tree matches requires performing a calculation on that entire tree.  It's not progressive.

How the heck do I find all matches?

Comment: Not sure that I understand the full context of this question. It appears that this is a homework question. If it is, please retag the question to add a homework tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem

sounds roughly like what you're trying to find (except that you're trying this on all subgraphs of an original graph as well, making it even harder).  I don't really know how you are defining "matches" (equality, pattern, color coordinated, sticks with chemicals on the end that ignite when struck?), so it might be quite a different problem.